# Ios table cell image download by NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest causes crash on table cell delete

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks

I am calling a block for table cell image download.

```
[self downloadImageWithURL:aa completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
            if (succeeded) {

            cell.imageView.image = image;


            ((DatabaseHelper *) [upcoming objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).image = image;
        }
        }];



- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void     (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if ( !error )
                           {
                               UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                               completionBlock(YES,image);
                           } else{
                               completionBlock(NO,nil);
                           }
                       }];
}
```

and it is working perfectly fine... but the problem is that, once for any cell the block is called, if i delete that cell before the completion of AsynchronousRequest, the app crashes. 
so how can I remove the call from NSoperation queue when i delete the cell.

[image: project log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I believe your code is crashing here: `[upcoming objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`. A quick fix would be to check whether your array is available or not, like this:

```
[self downloadImageWithURL:aa completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
        if (succeeded && upcoming && [upcoming lenght] > indexPath.row) {

        cell.imageView.image = image;


        ((DatabaseHelper *) [upcoming objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).image = image;
    }
    }];
```

A more clean solution would be to implement a controller, that stores all your requests. When you have this, its easy to cancel them. You should not do this inside your `UITableViewController` or `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Alright. Just in case: I think you may have timing issues when you reload data, for example: You load the image for cell 0, then you reload your data and cell 0 has another data source with no image. Now it may happend that the "old" image is getting attached to the new cell because it took too long to load.

Comment: ya... i am having dat problem now.. so i think the best solution would be to remove the operation from nsoperationqueue.. so m now learning about that

Comment: This would be a solution. A faster one would be to check the path of the images before you (re)attach it. You may use the `tag` field for this. Also you may subclass your objects to store the data you need in them.